# Create one RegEx to validate a username

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote this code to validate a username meets the given conditions, does anyone see how I can conbine the 2 RegExs into one? Code is c#

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the username meets conditions.
    /// Username conditions:
    /// Must be 1 to 24 character in length
    /// Must start with letter a-zA-Z
    /// May contain letters, numbers or '.','-' or '_'
    /// Must not end in '.','-','._' or '-_' 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">proposed username</param>
    /// <returns>True if the username is valid</returns>
    private static Regex sUserNameAllowedRegEx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]{0,23}[^.-]$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static Regex sUserNameIllegalEndingRegEx = new Regex(@"(\.|\-|\._|\-_)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static bool IsUserNameAllowed(string userName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)
            || !sUserNameAllowedRegEx.IsMatch(userName)
            || sUserNameIllegalEndingRegEx.IsMatch(userName)
            || ProfanityFilter.IsOffensive(userName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why turn two semi-legible regular expressions into one less-legible regular expression? Is your code not currently working right? What's the motivation for only using one regular expression?

Comment: Right my current regex allows for invalid characters as the last character, eg: aab$, or aab# are accepted by my regex, because the last clause takes any character that’s not . or -
should be [a-zA-Z0-9\_]$. So I need to fix that thx for the comment.

Comment: I just wanted one to see how it could be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the below should be what you want. The `\w` matches letters, digits, or `_`.

The [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the `(?<![-.])` part) allows `_` unless the preceding character was `.` or `-`.

```
@"^(?=[a-zA-Z])[-\w.]{0,23}([a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![-.])_)$"
```

Comment: @Nathan Wilfert: I should emphasize that the important part here is the negative lookbehind. That's what I think you're grasping for.

Comment: This answer seems to be the closes, but it will not allow one charater strings like 'a'.

Comment: @Nathan: That's an interesting point. It's sometimes tough to account for all the possibilities with regex. Try a modification: `@"^(?=[a-zA-Z])[-\w.]{0,23}([a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![-.])_)$"` I don't know how efficient that is (I suspect not very), but it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a greedy `+` on the last character class and make the middle class non-greedy:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]{0,22}?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,2}$"
```

this will disallow anything ending in any combination of `.`, `-`, or `_`. This isn't exactly what you have in your original regex, but I figure it's probably what you're going for.

Comment: This will pass usernames greater than 24 characters.

Comment: It also allows strings which end with all of the disallowed characters/combinations (I tested to be sure). Edit: and if your last character class were enforceable (which it's not), it would disallow characters that are allowed per spec.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` or `-` inside a character class. You do need to put the `-` immediately after the `[`, however. Also, the spec allows for `_` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._-]{0,21}([-.][^_]|[^-.]{2})$
```

This is really getting close (it meets all your requirements except that it requires at least three characters, rather than just one). Getting down to one would require some research on my part into C#'s regex capabilities, and I don't have time right now but I hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: This won't work; the ending is too broad. It will match "foo. " and "foo x", for example.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you have only four expressions to verify at the end of the string, right? So use the first regex to validate username and then check those four endings by using String functions. It won't consume much more time processing than a freaking regular expression.

Try the method string.EndsWith() to verify for '.', '-', '.*' or '-*'

Comment: This is what I'll end up doing, I just thought it would be a fun problem to figure out how to do this with one regex.