# Regex to validate username

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with this regex pattern:

`'/^[a-z0-9-_\.]*[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-_\.]*{4,20}$/i'`

What I'm trying to do is to validate the username. Allowed chars are alphanumeric, dash, underscore, and dot. The restriction I'm trying to implement is to have at least one alphanumeric character so the user will not be allowed to have a nickname like this one: `_-_.`

The function I'm using right now is:

```
function validate($pattern, $string){
    return (bool) preg_match($pattern, $string);
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT

As @mario said, yes,t here is a problem with `*{4,20}`.
What I tried to do now is to add `( )` but this isn't working as excepted:

`'/^([a-z0-9-_\.]*[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-_\.]*){4,20}$/i'`

Now it matches 'aa--aa' but it doesn't match 'aa--' and '--aa'.
Any other suggestions?

EDIT

Maybe someone wants to deny not nice looking usernames like "**_..**-a".
This regex will deny to have consecutive non alphanumeric chars:

`/^(?=.{4,20}$)[a-z0-9]{0,1}([a-z0-9._-][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9.-_]{0,1}$/i`

In this case `_-this-is-me-_` will not match, but `_this-is-me_` will match.

Have a nice day and thanks to all :)

Comment: did you try debugging with something like http://regexpal.com ?

Comment: Some people might consider it a cop-out, for but for things like this (that are easy to express without regular expressions) I personally prefer to stay awake from regex. Why not just loop through the characters, checking that they are all valid characters and at least one is alphanumeric?

Comment: could be that you are using lowercase a-z and always writing you usernames starting with uppercase? could you post some example data?

Comment: @Brandon it's more elegant to use regexes. + I will have a class with patterns, so I'll can easely dynamically add new patterns.

Comment: your regex is almost correct but you cannot have 2 quantifiers at once so [a-z0-9-_\.]*{4,20} is not working change it to [a-z0-9-_\.]*

Comment: @mightyuhu is correct, its saying "from 0 to unlimited times" and "from 4 to 20 times" which is illigal syntax

Comment: @s3v3n: "it's more elegant to use regexes" -- elegance is *nothing* if the code doesn't work. "I will have a class with patterns, so I'll can easely dynamically add new patterns" -- but you said that you didn't want to use more than one pattern because "This will add complexity."

Comment: Simple regex solution: `'/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])[\w\-.]{1,20}$/'`. See my answer for a breakdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to cram it all into one regex. Make your life simpler and use a two step-approach:

```
return (bool)
 preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_.-]{4,20}$/', $s) && preg_match('/\w/', $s);
```

The mistake in your regex probably was the mixup of `*` and `{n,m}`. You can have only one of those quantifiers, not `*{4,20}` both after another.

---

Very well, here is the cumbersome solution to what you want:

```
 preg_match('/^(?=.{4})(?!.{21})[\w.-]*[a-z][\w-.]*$/i', $s)
```

The assertions assert the length, and the second part ensures that at least one letter is present.

Comment: See my comment on Johnsyweb's answer to see why I can't (and dont want) to split it into 2 checks. And yes, now I clearly see that the problem is the mix of * and {4,20}. See edit.

Comment: @s3v3n: This is a great demonstration of the points that I make in my answer -- the two regular expressions are clear and easy to understand. @mario doesn't take advantage of the opportunity to provide tailored feedback to the user depending on which check fails, but you can!

Comment: @s3v3n: See update for the complex workaround. I'd still say this is not what you *should* be doing though.

Comment: Yes, that definetly works! I added 0-9, because as I said it can contain at least one number alphanumeric, so one number is enough.

Comment: Also I managed it to use only one lookahead (instead of two) for length validation. The final solution for me is:
`'/^(?=.{4,20}$)[\w._-]*[\w][\w._-]*$/i'`
IMHO 1 lookahead + second part that matches characters has similar complexity with a splited one version.

Comment: @s3v3n: Interesting. I didn't know you can do that. PCRE is elsewhise rigidly against variable-length assertions.  But beware that `[\w]` also matches the underscore in contrast to `[a-z0-9]`.

Comment: so actually it goes like this: `/^(?=.{4,20}$)[0-9a-z._-]*[0-9a-z][0-9a-z._-]*$/i`

Comment: @mario: PCRE does not allow variable length _lookbehind_. However,lookahead does not have this restriction and can be variable length.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably just a matter if finetuning, you could try something like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_.-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/m', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Matches:

- a_b  <- you might not want this.
- ysername
- Username
- 1254_2367
- fg3123as

Non-Matches:

- l__asfg
- AHA_ar3f!
- sAD_ASF_#"#T_
- *"#%"&#"E*
- __-.asd
- *username*
- 1_*_*_

Non-matches you might want to be matches:

- 1_5_2
- this_is_my_name

Comment: Actually I am saying that it should match from the begining of string. Putting the ^ inside the square brackets will have the effect of negation.

Comment: Also, as I said I'm trying to match not only alphanumeric, but also some more chars. The problem is to deny absence of at least one alphanumeric character.

Comment: yeah my bad i notice i wasnt clear enough in my answer, and edited it.

Comment: Actually after seeing this I liked the ideea to deny having more `-`, `.` or `-` together :)

Comment: the last ideea will work with this:
`/^(?=.{4,20}$)[a-z0-9]{0,1}([a-z0-9._-][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9.-_]{0,1}$/i`. ( `\w` matches unwanted `-` )

Comment: this allow you to have the username `_this.is-me_`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one instead:

```
'/[a-z0-9-_\.]*[a-z0-9]{1,20}[a-z0-9-_\.]*$/i'
```

Comment: I said not to start a letter or a digit, what actually does your regex, but contain at least one letter or digit, that's why i put [a-z0-9]+ in the midle.

Comment: Yes, this would do the trick, the only remaining problem would be to check the lenght of the username.

Comment: Since when is `strlen` out of the question?

Comment: Since I'm using a class with patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear to me that you should split this into two checks!

Firstly check that they are using all valid characters. If they're not, then you can tell them that they are using invalid characters.

Then check that they have at least one alpha-numeric character. If they're not, then you can tell them that they must.

Two distinct advantages here: more meaningful feedback to the user and cleaner code to read and maintain.

Comment: This will add complexity. Yes, that's not the end of the world, but this isn't really suck a complex regex to split it. And as I said before, I have a class Validator that will contain patterns, and I really don't want to complicate the things and implement 2 step validations there.

Comment: @s3v3n: I respectfully disagree. This will *remove* complexity. You've already complicated things here as proven by the facts that your regular expression doesn't do what you want it to and you are "trying to understand what's wrong".

Comment: I agree with Johnsyweb. What if you want to validate a file input next? its hard to find regexes for upload errors, 0-byte files etc.
you are restricting yourself too much by that architecture. it might works now but what if you want to go deeper?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, single regex solution (verbose):

```php
$re = '/ # Match password having at least one alphanum.
    ^                   # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])  # At least one alphanum.
    [\w\-.]{4,20}       # Match from 4 to 20 valid chars.
    \z                  # Anchor to end of string.
    /x';
```

In Action (short form):

```php
function validate($string){
    $re = '/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])[\w\-.]{4,20}\z/';
    return (bool) preg_match($re, $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][-\w.]{0,22}([a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![-.])_)$
```

From related question: [Create one RegEx to validate a username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902749/create-one-regex-to-validate-a-username/4902960#4902960)

Comment: As a first step this checks if the username starts with a letter, that's not exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?=.{3,31}$)[a-z0-9]{0,1}([a-z0-9._-][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9.-_]{0,1}$
```

This will Validate the username

1. start with an alpha
2. accept underscore dash and dots
3. no spaces allowed

Answer (score 0):

### Why don't you make it simpler like this?

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{3,9}`

- First letter should be Alphabetical.
- then followed by character or symbols you allowed
- length of the word should be between 4,10 (as explicitly force the first word)

[image]