# Devise gem - Do not allow special character in password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, passwords

I have used devise gem in rails application. password format for validation I found is

```
PASSWORD_FORMAT_USED_CURRENTLY = /\A
  (?=.{10,})          # Must contain 10 or more characters
  (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
  (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
  (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
  (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
/x
```

It works fine but I want two requirements to be fulfilled for my password
1) password must contain at least 6 letters ( it can be capital letters, small letters, digits or a combination of all ).

```
 PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
  (?=.{6,})          # Must contain 6 or more characters      
/x
```

2) the second criteria is that the password should not contain any special characters.

I don't know how to achieve this
what I found is only that how can I make compulsory the presence of special characters but not vice versa.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's an answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814780/regex-without-special-characters/6814901

Comment: this regex is ok but I am not able to implement it in my rails model file

Comment: Just wondering, what is the reason that one would need to prevent a user from entering a special character in a password?

Answer (score 0):

The second regex itself will handle both the cases.

```
 PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
  (?=.{6,})          # Must contain 6 or more characters
  (?=.*\w)           # Must contain capital letters, small letters, digits or a combination of all. Must not contain any special characters.
/x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this with password 123@12 and it accepts it.
this accepts special characters.